# Is there BTCPay Server for Ethereum?

Tags: payments

BTCPay Server is a self-hosted, open-source cryptocurrency payment processor for Bitcoin. It also allows to add other crypto currencies like Litecoin, Monero.

But is there a similar open-source project for Ethereum and ERC20 crypto currencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BTCPayServer's implementation for ethereum never really worked](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/pull/1730#issuecomment-1046311930) and [it was removed](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/pull/3182). I am the developer of [Hub20](https://hub20.io), which aims to be a self-hosted payment gateway for Ethereum (and compatible chains). It also provides support for any scaling solution that is compatible with Ethereum's RPC API (Arbitrum, Optimism, Polygon, xDAI-Gnosis, etc) and it integrates with [Raiden](https://raiden.network), which is Ethereum's analog to BTC Lightning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When it comes to payment processor it must be trusted first.

Comment: @hidev , that's exactly why we are talking about self-hosted systems. You can run it yourself - or let it be run by someone else that you trust directly.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Ethereum and ERC-20 tokens were added in BTCPay Server in Sep 2020
https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/pull/1730